# Select item from ComboBox to open web links on WebBrowser?

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

i've been looking around on how to make a combobox list choice to access a webpage on webbrowser. For example, if i choose the first item in the combobox wich is named "Google" then i would press on the button next to it to access google on the webbrowser.

I got this code but it doesn't work, once i choose the first option, nothing happens.

```
    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.google.ca/?gws_rd=ssl")
    End If
```

I seems so close, but i have no clues why it doesn't work..

Comment: when is that called?

Comment: When i press on the "Accept" button next to the combobox, it's just quick access to a list of web page links instead of having a bunch of button on the program.

Comment: if you dont have code for other selected indicies, it *wont* go anywhere else

Comment: There, even with 2 choices, it still isnt working. I'm still pretty rookie to the programming world, i might be missing something pretty obvious but i have no clue. here:                                                                             `If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
            WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.google.ca/?gws_rd=ssl")
        ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
            WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.bing.com/")
        End If`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Select Case ComboBox1.SelectedItem
        Case "Please Select"
            MsgBox("ERROR - No selection made in dropdown box!")
        Case "Google"
            WebBrowser1.Navigate("www.google.com")
        Case "Microsoft"
            WebBrowser1.Navigate("www.microsoft.com")
        Case "Stack Overflow"
            WebBrowser1.Navigate("www.stackoverflow.com")
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    '
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("Please Select")
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("Google")
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("Microsoft")
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("Stack Overflow")
    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
    '
End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_Navigating(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.Navigating
    ProgressBar1.Visible = True
    With ProgressBar1
        .Minimum = 0
        .Maximum = 50
        .Step = 5
    End With
    For index As Integer = 0 To 50 Step 5
        ProgressBar1.Value = index
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(35)
    Next
End Sub

End Class
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, glad to be of help and we all start of the same, as beginners :) If it works you could mark it as the answer too :))

Comment: Hell yeah, couldnt've asked for better, thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Is the item that's selected first? The index is 0-based. Meaning the first item in the list is index #0. Try it with selectedindex = 0.

Comment: now every choices endup opening the first selected. Even though i select the 3nd, it will open the 0nd..